# Mead fermentation

Tags: primary-fermentation

How fast can the fermentation take? Can it be completed in 3 or 4 days? I took my sg reading and it was 1.1. I added D47 yeast along with nutrients and enzymes. Didn't seem to start so I took a small sample of it to restart it. It went crazy for a couple days and than stopped. Thinking nothing about it I repeated it again. Nothing happened so I took a sg again. It was 1.01. Is that possible in 4 days time? If so is it still good?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, fermentation can be over it 3/4 days. 1100 to 1010 is 90 point drop over 4 days is a very rapid fermentation and I would expect the brew got rather warm, due to the heat generated by the yeast chewing through all that sugar.

It may still be good, but there is a chance your yeast will have got a bit too warm and produdced some more esters than usual. For some yeasts this can be great for others, can be less desirable. I would suggest having a small taste. The temp range for this yeast is [15-30°C (59-86°F)](https://www.lallemandbrewing.com/docs/products/tds/TDS_LALVIN_D47_ENG_DIGITAL.pdf), and it is described as a vigarous yeast by Northern brewer; given this it should all be good.

My experience of mead is that it is best to keep around 18-20 C like an ale, and once finished, bottle and leave for at least 2 weeks before consuming. Some meads I have left for a few years in corked wine bottles, and it kept evolving, I would not say got better as it really depends what you like, but it was all drinkable after 2 weeks in the bottle.